# Method for rounding ImageView corners yields different results

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an ImageView wherein I wanted to make the corners of the ImageView rounded. I found the following method to achieve this effect:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

This method works fine, I pass a Bitmap in, specify the radius, and the Bitmap the comes out has corners that are clipped and rounded appropriately.

For the usage, I have an activity where the user can either take a photo or choose one from the gallery or if he does neither, a default photo is selected. So I have the following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mPhoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Bitmap croppedImage = bitmapMethods.cropImage(mPhoto);
                finalPhoto = bitmapMethods.getRoundedCornerBitmap(croppedImage, 30);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(finalPhoto);
            }
            break;
        case Constants.CHOOSE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                mPhoto = bitmapMethods.decodeFile(selectedImage, mContext);
                Bitmap croppedImage = bitmapMethods.cropImage(mPhoto);
                finalPhoto = bitmapMethods.getRoundedCornerBitmap(croppedImage, 30);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(finalPhoto);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here `bitmapMethods.cropImage()` is a method that guarantees the length and width of the image are the same. Now the odd thing is that if I take a photo with the camera `case Constants.TAKE_PHOTO`, the corners are VERY rounded, almost a circular image comes out. If either the default photo or a selected photo is passed through the same method, the image comes out with slightly rounded corners as desired.

My question is why is that? I'm passing the same `int pixels` into each of the methods (in the above its 30) so why is it that taken photos come out as circles while chosen photos come out as rectangles with rounded edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "data" gives a thumbnail of the captured image. This would be very small compared to a 5MP image stored in the Gallery. Hence, a 30px rounded corner on 200px x 200px thumbnail would make it look like a circle, while on a 1024px x 768px image will make it feel like a rounded rectangle.

You could try http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image to store bigger images and reading them.